# Android: OkHttp request format and authorising apis

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using the Dirble Api and I am trying to test it to even get some results back but I think I might be doing it the wrong way. This is how I have been trying:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://api.dirble.com/v2/songs?token={MY_PROVIDED_ACCESS_TOKEN}")
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println("Test " + response.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized. Invalid or expired token."}
```

I assumed that this meant the tokens they provided me are just not functioning. So I generated a new one and same result.

This is there guidelines:

https://dirble.com/api-doc#introduction

I cant see anything I am doing wrong but since I am a novice in http requests, I would like to check there is nothing wrong with how I am doing it before I contact them to say the my access codes aren't working.

Comment: Its working fine for me. Same code. Different API key of course. Have you run out of the number of requests you can make? I see nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: No never used, and approved. I will message them. Thanks